# <img> not working in actionscript

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

In my flash 4.6 Air project, I have several thousands of html files in assets folder which are generated from some other software. Some html files having images.

Now to secure the html files I encrypt all of them. But when I decrypt them to a string and load to  via:

```
html.htmlLoader.loadString(decryptedString.toString());
```

or

```
html.htmlText = decryptedString.toString();
```

The images are not showing and a blank bordered box is showing with ALT text. These html files have javascript() and it is working.
The content of ("samople.htm") html file is like:

```
<P>Some Text</P>
<IMG SRC="../assets/sample/images/image.GIF" ALT="IMAGE.GIF" WIDTH="203"HEIGHT="105">
<P>Some Text</P>
```

To check the working When I load html by:

```
html.location = "/assets/sample/sample.htm";
```

Then it is showing the image. But when I use string by:

```
html.htmlText = '<p>some text</P><img src="../assets/sample/images/image.GIF" width="203" height="105"><p>some text</p>';
```

Then it is not showing image. I have tried to change from src="../assets/ . . ." to src="./assets/ . . ." or src="/assets/ . . ." or src="assets/ . . ."

My motto is to secure the html files in assets folder. Currently I can encrypt/decrypt them all but images are not showing.

I'm new in flex and air. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Here is my full sample code:
Flex/ActionScript

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="initiate()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public static var stream:FileStream;
            public static var stream2:FileStream;
            public static var file:File;

            public var readFile:ByteArray;

            public function initiate():void
            {
                file = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/sample/sample.htm");

                readFile = new ByteArray;
                stream = new FileStream();
                stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
                stream.readBytes(readFile);
                stream.close();

                html.htmlText = readFile.toString();//Not showing image.
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:HTML id="html" left="10" top="10" width="220" height="250"/>
    <mx:HTML id="html2" left="240" top="10" width="220" height="250"
             location="assets/sample/sample.htm"/><!--Showing Image-->
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

And HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>title</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function someFunction(someValue)
    {
        //some code;
    }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>This is image</P>
<P><IMG SRC="/assets/sample/images/myimage.gif" ALT="myimage.gif" WIDTH="203" HEIGHT="105"></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

myimage.gif is located at: assets/sample/images/myimage.gif

Answer (score 1):

Zeus rightly said htmlText property does not fully support mainly for **security reasons** in AIR. So when we place html contents through string the container is not in Application Sandbox (default value: false). But if you are sure that the external contents in html string are trusted then you have to set htmlLoader.placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a http debugger (in firebug/chrome debugger, use the 'net' tab), you can check out from which folder Flash is trying to load the images.

Probably its related to the .swf file location, not to the loaded html file.

Comment: I am using Flash Builder 4.6 with AIR and this is a windows application. What is important is when I use **html.location** it is working but when I convert the content of html file to string it is not showing the image only all other is working even javascript.

Comment: Still, if you think the path to the images is wrong, you should be able to debug that using a http debugger. Even in a AIR app, try 'Charles HTTP debugger'.

Comment: Path to the images is correct. To bought a new software and using it will be more cumbersome.

I repeat html.htmlText is not working but html.location is working.

Answer (score -1):

**HtmlText for the air with <img tags wont work, no matter what.** Adobe air will ignore all the <img tags for security purpose.

Work around is > spark textflow component. There are utilities to convert the htmltext into text flow format text and display it in the textflow supported componenents.

Comment: Thanks Mark and Zeus for reply but my problem is not sorted yet.

I have javascript in these html files and have AS <=> JS calling. 
Now, I have to save decrypted file temporarily on the user harddisk with all images and then use ".location" property which is working.

Comment: Is there any other way to use multiple html files with images and javascript in AIR. Thanks in advance.

Comment: text.htmlText property does not fully support the html tags, if you have to show the  html files then you have to use the <HTML air component to do that. There is a class HTmlLoader http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary may be this can help you some how.

Comment: One suggestion I can give is, use a Native applciation to do the encrypt and decrypt, let the air only display the html, the native application will return the html file decrypted when the air app requests for it using htmlloader.

Comment: Thank you very much zeus for again put me in the solution. I had already use the htmlLoader class (see the first code in my question). I read again htmlLoader class thoroughly and just put this line: **html.htmlLoader.placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox = true;** (default is false)
before 
**html.htmlLoader.loadString(fileToEncrypt.toString());** and ITS WORKING!!!.